# cakephp 3.8.8 Cannot convert value of type `string` to integer when saving field deadline as datetime

Tags: datetime, cakephp-3.8

Cakephp not saving the selected value of date field
I have form with field like:

```php
<? echo $this->Form->control('deadline', ['class' => 'form-control text-form-control', 'type' => 'datetime']); ?>
```

I can edit and change date with existing task in database,
but when I adding new task I have an error with massage:

```
Cannot convert value of type `string` to integer
InvalidArgumentException
```

In table model I have:

```php
<?php
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options) {
    foreach (['deadline'] as $key) {
        if (isset($data[$key]) && is_array($data[$key])) {
            $data[$key] = strtotime($data[$key]['year'] . '-' . $data[$key]['month'] . '-' . $data[$key]['day'] . ' ' . $data[$key]['hour'] . ':' . $data[$key]['minute']);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Stack trace:

```
Error: [InvalidArgumentException] Cannot convert value of type `string` to integer (\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Type\IntegerType.php:72)
#0 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Type\IntegerType.php(91): Cake\Database\Type\IntegerType->checkNumeric('2020-01-23 15:5...')
#1 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\TypeConverterTrait.php(36): Cake\Database\Type\IntegerType->toDatabase('2020-01-23 15:5...', Object(Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql))
#2 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Statement\PDOStatement.php(68): Cake\Database\Statement\StatementDecorator->cast('2020-01-23 15:5...', 'integer')
#3 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\ValueBinder.php(146): Cake\Database\Statement\PDOStatement->bindValue('c7', '2020-01-23 15:5...', 'integer')
#4 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Connection.php(332): Cake\Database\ValueBinder->attachTo(Object(Cake\Database\Statement\MysqlStatement))
#5 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\Retry\CommandRetry.php(67): Cake\Database\Connection->Cake\Database\{closure}()
#6 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Connection.php(336): Cake\Core\Retry\CommandRetry->run(Object(Closure))
#7 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Query.php(218): Cake\Database\Connection->run(Object(Cake\ORM\Query))
#8 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php(2129): Cake\Database\Query->execute()
#9 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php(2021): Cake\ORM\Table->_insert(Object(App\Model\Entity\Task), Array)
#10 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php(1934): Cake\ORM\Table->_processSave(Object(App\Model\Entity\Task), Object(ArrayObject))
#11 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php(1639): Cake\ORM\Table->Cake\ORM\{closure}()
#12 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Connection.php(737): Cake\ORM\Table->Cake\ORM\{closure}(Object(Cake\Database\Connection))
#13 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php(1640): Cake\Database\Connection->transactional(Object(Closure))
#14 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php(1935): Cake\ORM\Table->_executeTransaction(Object(Closure), true)
#15 \src\Controller\TasksController.php(65): Cake\ORM\Table->save(Object(App\Model\Entity\Task))
#16 \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php(609): App\Controller\TasksController->add()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Not very sure if this will help you **but** there are several things I can think of that you could try.
I think you are trying to do to much instead of relying on cakePHP 3 (Believe me, I feel you there because I have that habit myself).
As far as you add Timestamp behavior in your table by adding this in your table initialization:

```php
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');//<--- this one here
    ......
}
```

You **do not need** to take care of date time conversion provided the correct control has been used to capture the data in your view (as you have).
To note that you don't need to specify the type for the field 'deadline' if it is defined in the Data base as DateTime type (as it seems you did since you are trying to convert to something like *YYY-MM-DD HH:ii:SS* that look very much SQL DateTime).
CakePHP 3 will deduce it and act upon, from the database schema.
To wrap up, what I would try is to:

- Add the code I wrote above
- Remove the `beforeMarshal` code
- Lastly (but optional) change form line for the control for 'deadline' to:

```php
<? echo $this->Form->control('deadline', ['class' => 'form-control text-form-control']); ?>
```

After those changes check the received data in your controller using

```php
$data = $this->request->getData();
```

And then how the Entity looks after patching the data with

```php
$entity = $this->YourModel->patchEntity($youEntityModel, $data);
```

If you check `$entity` with something like `debug($entity)` you should be able to see the property 'errors' and if there is something strange, such as wrongly initialized or missformated  data and where, when cakePHP tries to format the data from the form to a suitable Entity object before saving.